# Uploading to Azure File Share from a Razor Page

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, razor-pages

I am trying to find an example of uploading a file to an Azure file share or blob storage from a razor page. I use this code from the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files)
but this copy files only to the local filesystem.
Now I found the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49651754/uploading-to-azure-file-share-from-a-razor-page) here on stackoverflow, but it won't work. I got the error in line

```cs
 var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(< your creds here>);
```

```cs
 the name "CloudStorageAccount does not exist in the current context"
```

I am using Visual Studio 2022, .Net Core 2.2. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try Googling the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Initially even I got the error.
[image]

- The NuGet package required for `CloudStorageAccount` is ***`WindowsAzure.Storage`***.

[image]

- But in Package Manager you can see `WindowsAzure.Storage` is deprecated.
- You can also see the alternate package ***`Azure.Storage.Blobs`*** is mentioned.
  [image]
- Install the latest ***`Azure.Storage.Blobs`*** NuGet package.
- When I tried to Install ***`Azure.Storage.Blobs`*** package, got the below error.

> ```cs
> "System.IO.Hashing doesn't support $(TargetFramework). Consider >updating the TargetFramework to netcoreapp3.1 or later." />
> ```

[image]

The error clearly says to update and use the `.NET Core` latest version.

I am able to clear the issue in `.Net Core 2.1` by installing the below NuGet Package.
***`Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement`***

[image]

- Add the using namespace `using Microsoft.Azure.Storage`

[image]

***My .csproj file***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My Conroller.cs***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAppMVC.Models;

namespace WebAppMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        
                        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        
                        var filename = file.FileName;
                        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("YOUR CREDS HERE");
                        var client = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
                        var shareref = client.GetShareReference("YOUR FILES SHARE");
                        var rootdir = shareref.GetRootDirectoryReference();
                        var fileref = rootdir.GetFileReference(filename);
                        await fileref.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
                        await fileref.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);

                        return Ok(new { fileuploaded = true });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest(new { error = "there was no uploaded file" });
            }
        }
      
    }
}
```